# Visual Studio Code keeps compiling even if I do not save changes

Tags: angular, typescript, compilation

As the topic says. VSC starts compilation even if there is no any single file change and it goes into loop compilation. I have Angular(6) project. I use following command:

```
ng serve
```

Another time when I search some file and go to it Visual Studio Code starts compilation again (there is no any changes). It drives me crazy when web browser referesh agian and againt. How to prevent this problem?

I use powershell. Here, you can see the output of compilation which I didn't triggered:
[image]

Comment: Mh, are you using some plugins?

Comment: Have you tried it with "npm start" ?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I use only two plugins: vscode-icons and VIsual Studio Keymap

Comment: Are you sure that the compilation is fired by VSC? I mean, if you close the window and do something else do the shell show compiling stuff over and over?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I fire ng serve via terminal which is built in VSC. Sometimes I do nothing and IDE recompile code by itself. Don't know why.

Comment: I understand. What about serving the application using an external terminal? You can even use cmd, just for test.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I've tried but it didn't work.

Comment: The only thing that I've found out is this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5368 . If that won't solve the problem I suggest you to open an issue on their repo

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the Solution and it is working Full Proof. One confession here, I don't know how it works but it works...

`ng serve --poll 1100`

Comment: This did not work for me, however, I found something else. 
If I start vscode first and let it finish its compiling of the code (probably done by the Angular Language Service - it shows the progress in the footer bar), then I can run ng serve without problems.
If I run ng serve first and start vscode later it will enter this infinite compiling loop...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add one of the `ng serve` options displayed below:

```
ng serve --no-live-reload
```

or

```
ng serve --live-reload false
```